# Sincronizar 3 Select com Loading + JQuery/ Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Olá, boa dia.

estou com meu aplicativo aqui na seguinte questão.

tenho a página **index.html**, 
nessa página eu tenho uma `<div>` para que seja apresentado o ***loading*** conforme o código abaixo:

```
<div id="loader" style="display: none;"> <img src="loading.gif" align="center" width="200" height="180">Carregando...</div>
```

Agora eu tenho o **arquivo.js**

```
 function onCarregaFunVeiEqu () {

    $.ajax({
        url: ''''''''getFun.php'''''''',
        type: ''''''''get'''''''',
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#loader").show();
            $("#loader").css({display:"block"});
        },
        success: function(response){
            var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                obj.forEach(function (o, index) {
                    onSincFun(o.cdfun, o.nmfun, o.nusen, o.nmatri);
                });


            $.ajax({
                url: ''''''''getVei.php'''''''',
                type: ''''''''get'''''''',
                async: false,
                success: function(response){
                    var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                        obj.forEach(function (o, index) {
                        onSincVei(o.cdve, o.nuplaca, o.detip, o.demdl);
                    });



                    $.ajax({
                        url: ''''''''getEquipe.php'''''''',
                        type: ''''''''get'''''''',
                        async: false,
                        success: function(response){
                            DeleteEqu();
                            var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                                obj.forEach(function (o, index) {
                                    onSincEqu(o.cdequ, o.deequ, o.dearea, o.nmobra);
                                });
                        }
                    });     
                }

            });
        },
        complete: function(data){
            //$("#loader").hide();

        }
    }).always (function() {
        $("#loader").show();
        $("#loader").css({display:"block"});
    }).done (function() {
        $("#loader").hide();
        $("#loader").css({display:"none"});
    });

}
```

o que acontece é :

o Loading.. ele aparce, porém já some...
e enquanto isso ele tá sincronizando.. 
ou seja ele tinha que sincronizar TUDO para depois desaparecer o Loading...

alguém tem uma sugestão?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você colocou as condições de hide ao final da primeira requisição ajax, e são 3

Tente isso:

```
function onCarregaFunVeiEqu () {

$.ajax({
    url: ''''''''getFun.php'''''''',
    type: ''''''''get'''''''',
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function(){
        $("#loader").show();
        $("#loader").css({display:"block"});
    },
    success: function(response){
        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
            obj.forEach(function (o, index) {
                onSincFun(o.cdfun, o.nmfun, o.nusen, o.nmatri);
            });


        $.ajax({
            url: ''''''''getVei.php'''''''',
            type: ''''''''get'''''''',
            async: false,
            success: function(response){
                var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                    obj.forEach(function (o, index) {
                    onSincVei(o.cdve, o.nuplaca, o.detip, o.demdl);
                });



                $.ajax({
                    url: ''''''''getEquipe.php'''''''',
                    type: ''''''''get'''''''',
                    async: false,
                    success: function(response){
                        DeleteEqu();
                        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                            obj.forEach(function (o, index) {
                                onSincEqu(o.cdequ, o.deequ, o.dearea, o.nmobra);
                            });
                    }
                }).done (function() {
                   $("#loader").hide();
                   $("#loader").css({display:"none"});
                });     
            }

        });
    },
    complete: function(data){
        //$("#loader").hide();

    }
    }).always (function() {
        $("#loader").show();
        $("#loader").css({display:"block"});
    }).done (function() {
        //$("#loader").hide();
        //$("#loader").css({display:"none"});
    });
```

Eu comentei o código que esconde a div de loading, e coloquei ela no final da ultima requisição sua.

o **.done()** executa no fim da requisição

e `$("#loader").hide();` esconde o loader

Comment: como eu posso fazer para que o "Loading" fique visível até o final ?

Já fiz ele separado...
Tinha criado 3 function.. com sync = False;
também não deu certo.

Depois eu fiz 3 function com sync = True;
também não deu muito certo.

mais pelo que eu sei não é muito bom deixar o sync = false.
pois pode "congelar" a tela do usuário.

Comment: parece que deu certo!

Obrigado, faltou atenção rsrs...
Estava batendo cabeça faz uns 3 dias...


já aproveitando o gancho.
tem alguma coisa aqui fórum ou exemplo...

eu não sei o nome,
de ficar a tela toda "travada/ embaçada" e o loading carregando ...